# Spacing between bottom of page and content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My main container on my page holds all of the content, and it is supposed to go the entire length of the page. BUT for some reason there is a tiny gap on the bottom that shows the background behind it. Any Thoughts?
Much thanks.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GS4 Concept Home Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="unicss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="Script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Script/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"><h1 class="headover">You Are Home.</h1>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Galaxy S4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Verizon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ATT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sprint</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">T-Mobile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="container">//breaks for testings sake
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div><center><img src="Images/Galaxy_Family.jpg" width="70%" /></center>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
    background-image:url(Images/backgroundmain.jpg);
    min-width:100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    margin:0;
}

.headover{
    color:#333;
    float:right;
}
.headover:hover{
    color:white;
}

#gfamily{
    margin:auto
}

#header{
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#666;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:54px;
    display:block;
    min-width:1000px;
}

#container{
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:auto;
    width:70%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.nav{
    margin-left:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#999;
}

.navigation {
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    margin-top:15px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.navigation li {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}

.navigation li a {
    background:#262626;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding:8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    color:#666;
}

.navigation ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    margin:0 0 0 -1px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}

.navigation ul li {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border-top:none;
}

.navigation ul a {
    display:block;
    height:15px;
    padding:8px 7px 13px 7px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}

.navigation ul a:hover {
    color:#666;
}
```

JavaScript (If it matters..?):

```
// Executes the function when DOM will be loaded fully
$(document).ready(function () {
// hover property will help us set the events for mouse enter and mouse leave
    $('.navigation li').hover(
// When mouse enters the .navigation element
        function () {
//Fade in the navigation submenu
            $('ul', this).fadeIn(); // fadeIn will show the sub cat menu
        },
// When mouse leaves the .navigation element
        function () {
//Fade out the navigation submenu
            $('ul', this).fadeOut(); // fadeOut will hide the sub cat menu
        }
    );
});
```

[image: Shows the space on the bottom of the page]

Comment: Can you upload to jsfiddle or something? Other than that, I'd say try putting `margin-bottom: 0px;` on `#container` and/or `padding-bottom: 0px;` on `body`

Comment: Also, make sure the margin-bottom on the container goes after your `margin: auto;`, or just change that line to `margin: 0px auto;`

Comment: Try adding `line-height: 0` to the center tag or `display: block` to the image

Comment: Uh.. that code is pretty bad. Would recommend you to use @kamuken solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue with your markup.

```
<div id="container">//breaks for testings sake
    <br>
</div><center>...</center>
```

Try:

```
<div id="container">//breaks for testings sake
    <br>
    <center>...</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Duh, this worked perfectly. i dont know how i didnt see this, thank you so much!

Comment: don't use <br> for content height if you would like an valid html code

Comment: I don't think this warrants a vote down. Anyway, <br> is valid HTML.

Comment: this is an invalid html structure. the <br> tag used in text (breakline...)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to keep the image outside of the main container, you can change the img *display* property to *block* as opposed to the default *inline* value. I would also recommend replacing the center tag with a *margin* property set to *auto*, because center tags are [not supported in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp).

```
img{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have an invalid html structure, try this solution instead

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GS4 Concept Home Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="unicss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="Script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Script/main.js"></script>

<style>
.container {
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    background:white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.centered {
    text-align:center;
}

.responsiveimg {
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1 class="headover">You Are Home.</h1>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Galaxy S4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Verizon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ATT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sprint</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">T-Mobile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="centered">
        <img src="Images/Galaxy_Family.jpg" class="responsiveimg" />
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```